# Lightbox Not Working with jQuery

Tags: ajax, lightbox

I have a problem with lightbox after loading the following script in my page:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('answercheck', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^\b5\b$/.test(value);
}, "please type the correct answer (this is anti-spam)");

// validate contact form
$(function() {
    $('#contact').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        answer: {
            required: true,
            answercheck: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "please enter your name",
            minlength: "your name must consist of at least 2 characters"
        },
        email: {
            required: "please enter your email address"
        },
        answer: {
            required: "sorry, wrong answer! (this is anti-spam)"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit({
            type:"POST",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            url:"process.php",
            success: function() {
                $('#contact :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $('#contact').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    $(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                    $('#success').fadeIn();
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#contact').fadeTo( "slow", 0.15, function() {
                    $('#error').fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });
      }
    });
 });
```

I have read about .live() and read this page http://api.jquery.com/live/ but I am a newbie and have trouble implementing it in my script. Any help please?
thank you

Comment: Ask a more precise question. No live() in code example.

Comment: well the live() apparently is used to fix the issue, i just dont know how to implement it